# Laravel Routes Group-Prefix using variable

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm trying to use a variable (which contains a value stored in the session) as a prefix to all my group routes, so I can make it more readable and clean.

Basically I want to transform this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles', 'PreventBackHistory']], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@profile')->name('admin.profile');
    Route::get('editRegs', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@editRegs')->name('admin.edit');
    Route::get('settings', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@settings')->name('admin.settings');

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles', 'PreventBackHistory']], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@index')->name('user.dashboard');
    Route::get('profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@profile')->name('user.profile');
    Route::get('settings', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@settings')->name('user.settings');

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles', 'PreventBackHistory']], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@index')->name('manager.dashboard');
    Route::get('profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@profile')->name('manager.profile');
    Route::get('settings', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@settings')->name('manager.settings');

});
```

Into something like this:

```
$role = session()->get('role');
Route::group(['prefix' => $role, 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles', 'PreventBackHistory']], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@index')->name($role.'.dashboard');
    Route::get('profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@profile')->name($role.'.profile');
    Route::get('editRegs', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@editRegs')->name('admin.edit');
    Route::get('settings', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@settings')->name($role.'.settings');
}
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... there is no session at this point ... the session functionality is available via a middleware and the request has not been dispatched through the middleware at this point (the routes aren't even registered at this point) ... also routes are not supposed to be dynamic like this; if you cached your routes they would only be setup for 1 role, not dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like this. It's worked on me.

Open app/Http/Providers/AppServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
public function boot()
{
$role = Session::get('role');
    app()->bind('role', function() use ($role){
        return [
                'role' => $role
        ];
     });
}
```

In routes/web.php

```
define('role', app()->make('role')['role']);
Route::group(['prefix' => $role, 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles', 'PreventBackHistory']], function() {
Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@index')->name(role.'.dashboard');
Route::get('profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@profile')->name(role.'.profile');
Route::get('editRegs', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@editRegs')->name('admin.edit');
Route::get('settings', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@settings')->name(role.'.settings'); });
```

In blade;

```
{{ route(app()->make('role')['role'].'.dashboard') }}
```

You can try to send "app()->make('role')['role']" as a variable to your blade for more understanding.

Comment: It works, I just have to change some stuff, but it'll do. Thank you.